# How do I construct a regular expression to get an undetermined number of mathches like

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

As part of a desktop application, I'm trying to extract my Facebook friends out of an HTML list that is inside an HTML file that comes with the package of downloaded Facebook data. The list is like

```
<h2>Friends</h2>
<ul>
   <li>John Skeet</li>
   <li>Donald Knuth</li>
   <li>Mark Zuckerberg</li>
   .
   .
   .
</ul>
```

(except there is no whitespace, no newlines; I just wrote it like that for beauty in this thread). So I'd be trying to get `John Skeet`, `Donald Knuth`, `Mark Zuckerberg`, ... out of that.

**Note:** The list would be finite. The "..." I've been writing doesn't mean it goes on infinitely.

My program so far is

```
    private static readonly string _friendsRegex = "<h2>Friends</h2><ul>something</ul>"; // regular expression for matching friends' names

    static void Main ( string [] args )
    {
        try
        {   
            if ( args.Length != 1 ) throw new Exception("Unfriendly.exe expects 1 parameter, the full path the data of your Facebook acount");

            using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("/html/friends") )
            {
                String html = sr.ReadToEnd();
                HashSet<string> curfriends = new HashSet<string>();
                Regex fregx = new Regex(String.Format(@"{0}",Program._friendsRegex), RegexOptions.Compiled);
                foreach (Match thisfriend in fregx.Matches(html))
                    curfriends.Add(thisfriend.Value);
                // ...
            }
        }
```

and I'm wondering what `_friendsRegex` shoud be, or if it's even possible to construct such a regex.

Comment: what about "<li>[\w ]+</li>"? The blank after \w is intended ;)

Comment: Get "unexpected escape sequence" error on the `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Regex: `<li>([a-zA-Z ]+)</li>`

Keep in mind that you need to get the second `capture group`, the first one is the whole match. You can get it like this:

```
foreach (Match match in fregx.Matches(html))
    curfriends.Add(match.Groups[1]);
```

This regex only matches names that use normal letters and spaces, you can add characters as required in between the `[]` or simply use all except `<` by replacing `[a-zA-z ]` with `[^<]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
<li>([^<]+)<\/li>
```

And grab matches of capture group 1. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL3nX3/1)

`[^<]+` matches one or more characters, that are not `<`

Comment: What does that \g do exatly?

Comment: @AbolishtheIRS It's in some languages for global matching (return all matches) others have own functions for this. Idk if this exists in .NET regex, [see here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_25736176.html).